# SQL Reporting Services - Restrict Export Formats

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to limit export formats only PDF and Excel ?

Comment: Are you looking to do this per report, or for the whole server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comment out or remove the formats you want to exclude in the Render section of **rsreportserver.config** in

```
..\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.<n>\Reporting Services\ReportServer
```

Comment: I wanted to add that there is also the possibility of using the Visible attribute.

<Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.XmlDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering" Visible="False"/>